# Organizing Dependencies

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to organize my unmanaged .dll dependencies in my Visual Studio solution but unless the DLLs are strewn about the top level of my solution they do not get built into the application's directory and then the application fails to run. I have done a lot of Googling on the subject and there seems to be a solution in the form of an app.config setting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblybinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatepath="lib" />
    </assemblybinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I have a folder in my solution called "lib" and Copy Local is set to true for all files in the folder but the application is still unable to run. **How can I keep my Visual Studio solution organized without breaking my application?**

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found to solve this issue is through windows .bat files.
 If there is a way to encode extra search paths into an unmanaged executable, I would like to know!

Here is an example of what I do:

```
SET PATH=$~dp0plugins\MY_PLUGIN\Debug;%PATH%
vcvars32.bat
devenv build\MY_PROJECT.sln
```

The first line adds the path of where I want visual studio to find my dll's in.

The second line ensures that the 'right' visual studio will open up. IE: if I have my environment set for VS2010, I dont want VS2012 to open up by default.

The last line invokes the IDE to open up my sln file.

The visual studio that opens up now has a path to the Debug folder of one of my plugins. When I debug my application, the correct dll will be found, loaded, and debugged with no issue - I verify this under the Debug->Windows->Modules panel.

This only works for the Debug configuration. If I want to run the release configuration, I change the .bat file to say 'Release', close Visual Studio and re-run the .bat file.

I apply this same pattern to running my executable. Set up the environment of where I want my dll's to come from and then execute my executable:

```
SET PATH=$~dp0plugins\Debug;%PATH%
... Repeat for other dll locations
"%~dp0Debug\MY_EXECUTABLE.exe" %*
```

[SS64](http://ss64.com/nt/) is an invaluable resource to figure out what you can do in .bat files